# Linking General meaning of Naturality from Tom Leinster book and the commutativity of diagrams

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

Here is the definition of naturality from pg.50 (Problem 2.1.14) in Tom Leinster "Basic Category Theory":

$\overline {A' \xrightarrow {\text{p}} A \xrightarrow {\text{f}} G(B) \xrightarrow {\text{G(q)}} G(B')} = (F(A') \xrightarrow {\text{F(p)}} F(A) \xrightarrow{\bar{f}} B \xrightarrow {\text{q}} B')$

For all $p,f$ and $q.$

And here is the definition of commutativity of a diagram in general which in algebraic topology is usually interpreted as naturality

Here is an example of a commutative diagram:

$$![commutative triangle][1]$$

We have the above triangle such that $$g\circ f = h.$$

Here's another example:

[image: commutative square]

Where we have the above square such that $$h\circ f = k\circ g.$$

Could someone tell me how can we go from the general definition of naturality given by Tom Leinster to the definition of naturality via the commutative square given above?

Comment: Commutativity of specific diagrams is naturality. It’s just a way of writing equations.

Comment: @ZhenLin yeah but how can I go from the given equation in the book to the commutativity of a diagram and vice versa?

Comment: As you wrote yourself: "the square commutes" means the same thing as $h \circ f = k \circ g$. Substitute the appropriate terms for $f, g, h, k$ and you're done. It's nothing hard or tricky.

Comment: @ZhenLin I do not know how to do this actually, can you show me please? ...... what is corresponding to $h,f,k,g$ respectively in the given equation of the book?

Comment: OK, I see the problem: the equation you wrote is not the general definition of naturality! That is the definition of naturality applied to the definition of adjointness.

Comment: Then how can we go to the commutative diagrams from this definition @ZhenLin ?

Comment: I don't know what question you want to ask anymore. If you want to express the equation you mentioned as a commutative diagram, draw a hexagon. If you want to see how the equation you mentioned is an instance of naturality, apply the definition to the map $\textrm{Hom} (A, G B) \to \textrm{Hom} (F A, B)$ given by $f \mapsto \bar{f}$.

Comment: @ZhenLin can you please draw the hexagon for me? I do not know how to do that, specifically because the arguments before and after the arrows are different on both sides

Comment: Actually, there is no hexagon. I misread. As I said, this is the definition of naturality applied to $f \mapsto \bar{f}$, which is a map $\textrm{Hom} (A, G B) \to \textrm{Hom} (F A, B)$. You can draw this as a square as usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow Leinster carefully (precisely, Chapter 4, after he introduces Representability and the Hom bifunctor), he gives the precise definition of what he means by the "naturality" assumption in the definition of an adjunction. Namely, given a pair of functors in opposite directions :
$$F : \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B},\text{ }G : \mathcal{B} \to \mathcal{A}$$ an adjunction between $F$ and $G$ (with $F \dashv G$) is a natural isomorphism $$\theta : \mathcal{A}(-,G(-)) \xrightarrow{\sim} \mathcal{B}(F(-),-)$$, both of which are bifunctors $\mathcal{A}^{op} \times \mathcal{B} \to Set$

If you unravel the definition of a natural transformation (as defined in Chapter 1), you will get the required relation in the definition of an adjunction (which you have mentioned in the beginning).

Precisely, the data of a natural isomorphism $\theta$ as above consists of precisely, for each object $(A,B) \in \mathcal{A}^{op} \times \mathcal{B}$, an isomorphism $\theta_{(A,B)} : \mathcal{A}(A,GB) \xrightarrow{\sim} \mathcal{B}(FA,B)$, mapping $f \mapsto \overline {f}$, such that for any arrow $(A,B) \xrightarrow{(p^{op},q)} (A',B')$ in the product category $\mathcal{A}^{op} \times \mathcal{B}$, the following square commutes in Set :

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\mathcal{A}(A,GB) @>{\theta_{(A,B)}}>> \mathcal{B}(FA,B)\\
@V{G(q) \circ - \circ p}VV @V{q \circ - \circ F(p)}VV\\
\mathcal{A}(A',GB') @>{\theta_{(A',B')}}>> \mathcal{B}(FA',B')
\end{CD}

Take any map $f : A \to GB$ in $\mathcal{A}$. Following the path (top arrow, right arrow) in the above square gives you the map $q \circ \overline{f} \circ F(p)$. Following the path (left arrow, bottom arrow) in the above square gives you the map $\overline{G(q) \circ f \circ p}$. The commutative of the above square suggests the equality of these two maps.

Conversely, the existence of a bijection $\mathcal{A}(A,GB) \xrightarrow{\sim} \mathcal{B}(FA,B)$ for each $A \in \mathcal{A}$, $B \in \mathcal{B}$ subject to the above equality (as given in the definition of an adjunction by Leinster in Chapter 2) will give you a natural isomorphism $\mathcal{A}(-,G(-)) \xrightarrow{\sim} \mathcal{B}(F(-),B)$.